# Backbone.js requires json2.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

From the site:

> Backbone's only hard dependency is either Underscore.js ( > 1.4.3) or Lo-Dash. For RESTful persistence, history support via Backbone.Router and DOM manipulation with Backbone.View, include json2.js, and either jQuery ( > 1.4.2) or Zepto.

Why is json2.js mentioned? I have run my app in ie7-9 among other browsers without requiring this file and it works. Is this a performance thing?

Comment: It's needed for [`Backbone.sync()`](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync), which [assumes `JSON.stringify()` is defined](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/0.9.9/backbone.js#L1437), whether [by browser or library](http://caniuse.com/#feat=json).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

json2.js provides `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` functions, which Backbone depends on. [They've been included in browsers for a while](http://caniuse.com/json) but it's probably listed in case your environment doesn't include it, or you want a consistent implementation in your app.

Comment: Note that older Internet Explorers (in fact <= IE 8) do not implement these methods, so one needs to include an extra JSON API to do that.

Answer (score 2):

That script adds JSON functionality to older browsers that will look just like native functionality that exists in newer browsers

https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers have suggested, you only need to download and include the "manual" JSON library if you need to support older browsers; otherwise your browser will have it built in (which is how you saw Backbone work without issue).

For the exact list of which browsers have/don't have JSON built in, see: http://caniuse.com/#feat=json